# How can I apply gradient in excel row using xssfworkbook in c#

Tags: c#, npoi

set gradient in outline in excel cell background in xssfworkbook using namespace npoi with c# and display output ?

NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Spreadsheet.CT_Fill myGradientFill = NPOI.OpenXmlFormats.Vml.CT_Fill.Factory.newInstance();

Comment: Did you apply your `myGradientFill` to a cell?

Comment: Factory is not working in C#

Comment: please have a look [here](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/blob/master/ooxml/OpenXmlFormats/Spreadsheet/Styles/CT_Fill.cs) how this works. Your posted code makes less sense to me